# Почему Ajax JQuery отправляет 2 запроса к серверу на Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Доброго Времени Суток!
Столкнулся с возможной проблемой. Отправляю по клику на кнопку, запрос на сервер на Django. Код работает, но почему-то Jquery отправляет 2 одинаковых запроса и соответственно возвращает 2 одинаковых ответа.
Вот код JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $( "#exit" ).click(function(){
    $('#contentresp').fadeOut("slow").html("");
    setTimeout(function(){$("#respwindow").animate({
    height: "0%",
    width:"0%"
        }, 200 );
     $('#menu').fadeIn("slow");},400);
     $("#respwindow").hide()
 })

$("[data-v]").click(main_menu)
function main_menu(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/change_views/",
        data:{
            'view':$(this).data('v'),
        },
        cache:false,
        success:
        function(data){
            $("#respwindow").show().animate({
                width:"100%"
            }, 200 ).animate({
            height:"100%"
            }, 200 );
            $('#menu').fadeOut("slow");
            setTimeout(function(){$('#contentresp').html(data);
                                 $('#contentresp').fadeIn("slow")},500);
        }
   });

}
}
)
```

Вот код urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from .views import (base,main_menu,change_views,change_order)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'base/$', base, name='base'),
    url(r'mainmenu/$', main_menu, name='mainmenu'),
    url(r'change_views/$', change_views, name='change_views'),
    url(r'change_order/$', change_order, name='change_order'),
]
```

Вот код view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import MySkills

# Create your views here.
def base(request):
    title = "Base"
    context = {
        "title":title,
    }
    return render(request,"base.html",context)
def main_menu(request):
    title = "Main menu"
    context = {
    "title":title,
    }
    return render(request,"main.html",context)

def change_order(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        name_p = request.GET.get('name_p')
        stage = request.GET.get('stage')
        dateStat = request.GET.get('dateStat')
        context = {"name_p":name_p,"stage":stage,"dateStat":dateStat}
        return render_to_response("page/items/change_order.html",context)


def change_views(request):
    if request.is_ajax():
        get_view =request.GET.get('view')
        address = get_view.replace(" ","_")
        if get_view == "My skills":
            lang = MySkills.objects.filter(skill_type="PL")
            fw = MySkills.objects.filter(skill_type="FW")
            sklAp = MySkills.objects.filter(skill_type="AS")
            anSkl = MySkills.objects.filter(skill_type="AnS")
            context = {"lang": lang,"fw": fw, "sklAp": sklAp, "anSkl":   anSkl, "Vtitle":get_view}
        elif get_view == "My projects":
            context = {"Vtitle":get_view}

        else:
            title = get_view
            answer = 'I am Ajax!'
            context = {'title':title,'answer':answer}
            return render_to_response('page/About_me.html',context)
        return render_to_response('page/'+address+'.html',context)
```

Html главной страницы.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}
{% block head %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css\my_css\maincss.css'%}">
{% endblock head %}
{% block content %}
<div>
    <div id="menu" class="outer" style="height:100%; width: 100%; position:absolute;z-index:0">
        <div class="inner" style="">
           {% include "page/menu.html"%}
        </div>

    </div>
       <div id="respwindow" class="windowResponse">
           <span id="exit" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove size-36" style="position:relative; float:left;color:red;z-index:40"></span>
           <div id="contentresp">

           </div>

{% block scripts %}
<script src="{% static 'js\my_js\ajax_request.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

обертка base.html

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" style="height:100%">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Optional theme -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-cCueBR6CsyA4/9szpPfrX3s49M9vUU5BgtiJj06wt/s="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--My css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css\oth_css\stars.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css\my_css\fontsstyle.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{%static 'css\my_css\basestyle.css' %}">
    {% block head %}

    {% endblock %}
    <style>
        .outer:before {
            content: '';
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }

        .inner {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: middle;
            margin-left: -0.35em;
        }

        .outer {
            text-align: center;
        }

    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="height:100%; width: 100%; overflow:hidden">
       <div id=#title>
         {% block content %}

         {% endblock %}
       </div>
         {% block scripts %}

         {% endblock %}
       <script src="{%static 'js\oth_js\space_bg.js'%}"></script>
       </body>
</html>
```

[image: Get запрос]

Так и должно быть? Или есть ошибка в коде? 
Весь код можно увидеть на моем github https://github.com/Lairion/Portfolio

Comment: Не должно, но сходу ошибки не видать

Comment: а покажите свой html

Comment: Может быть пальцем в небо попаду, но попробуйте проверить в режиме "инкогнито". Были у меня случаи когда запросы задваивались их за расширений браузера подтягивающих свою копию jquery.

Comment: Прием, пальцем в небо, не работает :(

Comment: У Вас в файле `main.html` блок `script` находится внутри блока `content`. В результате подстановки в `base.html` блок `script` будет включен два раза. Дальше думаю Вы поняли)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас блок `scripts` вложен в блок `content`:

*base.html:*

```
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
{% endblock %}
```

*main.html:*

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
    </div>

    {% block scripts %}
        <script ...>
    {% endblock %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Думаю, если вынести блок `script`, у Вас все будет работать как должно:

*main.html:*

```
{% extends base.html %}
{% block content %}
    <div>
    </div>
{% endblock content %}

{% block scripts %}
    <script ...>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!! как рейтинг подниметься обязательно поставлю бал!!!!

Comment: Очень выручил!!!!